# What does Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.UrlPathEncode do?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I found [a brilliant example](http://eksith.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/whitelist-santize-htmlagilitypack/) of a HTML sanitizer using HTMLAgilityPack. In the code, the `Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder` class is used:

```
// AntiXss
a.Value = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.UrlPathEncode(a.Value);
```

I cannot find the assembly containing this class, I would prefer to not have another dependency in my project, and the sanitizer works without this line. However removing this call may leave a security breach in the code.

In order to decide for or against using this assembly, I would like to know: **what does this method actually do?**

Comment: Similar to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder.urlpathencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) maybe (see examples at the end of the article).

Comment: I think this gets used for sanitizing any src/href type attributes which contain a url (this can get xss hijacked with `href='javascript:badthings()'` for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [source code](https://wpl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#release/v4.3/Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder/Encoder.cs)

From the source code for the method

```
/// <summary>
/// URL-encodes the path section of a URL string and returns the encoded string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">The text to URL path encode</param>
/// <returns>The URL path encoded text.</returns>
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage(
    "Microsoft.Design",
    "CA1055:UriReturnValuesShouldNotBeStrings",
    Justification = "This does not return a full URL so the return type can be a string.")]
public static string UrlPathEncode(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) 
    { 
        return input; 
    } 

    // DevDiv #211105: We should make the UrlPathEncode method encode only the path portion of URLs. 
    string schemeAndAuthority; 
    string path; 
    string queryAndFragment; 
    bool validUrl = UriUtil.TrySplitUriForPathEncode(input, out schemeAndAuthority, out path, out queryAndFragment);

    if (!validUrl) 
    { 
        // treat as a relative URL, so we might still need to chop off the query / fragment components 
        schemeAndAuthority = null; 
        UriUtil.ExtractQueryAndFragment(input, out path, out queryAndFragment); 
    } 

    return schemeAndAuthority + HtmlParameterEncoder.UrlPathEncode(path, Encoding.UTF8) + queryAndFragment; 
}
```

You will have to dig deeper to get to all the moving parts in encoding the uri. Usually I would recommend looking into the unit tests to see what is expected of the component but there is no tests on the `Encoder` class at first glance :(